# XSLT Style sheet not returnign child element

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT an I have a basic style sheet that is not returning the child element.
Can any one help?

Thanks.

Style Sheet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v17"> 
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
        <xsl:template match="/Get_Worker_Response "> 

         <xsl:template match="/wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker/wd:Worker_Data">
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_ID" />
                </xsl:template>

   </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can't have an `xsl:template` inside another template, for one thing.  What does your source XML look like?

Comment: Thanks JLRishe for the reply. I did not receive notification of your response. I solved the issue. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a syntax error; you can't have nested `xsl:template` elements.

Comment: Dan, I wasn't getting an error the style sheet was just returning the root element. I solved the problem. Thanks for taking the time to reply.